# Spring Boot Rest API - Unable to upload file

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, netflix-zuul

We are using Spring Boot 1.5.17.RELEASE.
We have multiple services and using zuul service as API gateway and eureka service as service registry.

Controller method in License Service:

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{licenseId}/upload")
public ResponseEntity<ValidationResponse> upload(@PathVariable Long licenseId,
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws GenericException {
```

When I tested the above API method individually (without API gateway), able to upload files:

```
http://localhost:8061/licenses/7/upload
```

But when I tested with API gateway, I got the exception:

```
http://localhost:8052/api/license-service/licenses/7/upload

Status is 400 Bad Request

ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]
```

Why it is NOT working with Zuul API Gateway ? Any extra configuration is required ?

Comment: The exception message states it quite clearly that the `file` expected as a part of request is not present.  You can use something like Postman to POST files to the API and test.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @Sid I think you didn't read my question completely. I am able to test upload file (Using Postman) if I access the API individually but with Zuul API gateway its not working

Comment: Sorry if I missed it.  But the exception is still the same, stating that the file is not found.  Perhaps you are trying to post it from a location where file is not present.

Comment: @ No, its there. After calling "http://localhost:8061/licenses/7/upload" successfully. I just changed the URL to "http://localhost:8052/api/license-service/licenses/7/upload" . its giving 400 and on console I can see that message

Comment: If that's a POST, you will also need a body with multipart file.  How are you using that in both the examples?

Comment: Yes, I am using in both the requests. Basically when we use Zuul Gateway it will redirect to configured service internally. Unfortunately its working individually but  not working with Zuul.

Comment: There was an issue in Spring Boot with Multipart PUT requests. (Although it was fixed maybe it somehow still works incorrectly with the proxied requests...) So first test what happens if you change the controller annotation to @PostMapping.